# Posso editar personalizar a tabela AspNetUsers do Identity?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Galera tenho um projeto que possui uma tabela de `USUARIOS`. E agora estamos migrando para `AspNet.Identity` que já possui uma tabela porém chamada `AspNetUser` e com seus próprios campos. E minha tabela `USUARIOS` tem relacionamentos com Pessoas e  outras tabelas do meu contexto.

Até pensei em manter as 2 tabelas e no momento de registrar novo usuário, ou fazer    update do usuario, alterar nas 2. Mas manter 2 tabelas com dados duplicados não me parece correto.

Então como personalizar a AspNetUser para que tenha o nome, os campos e
relacionamentos que preciso? Sendo que iniciei o projeto sem autenticação e adicionei o Entity a partir do Nuget.
Outro dado é que estou utilizando CodeFirst no Contexto geral da aplicação. E na imagem a seguir está minha tabela USUARIO existente, que não pode ser modificada. Acredito que a AspNetUserRules poderia vir a ser a PERFIS também, certo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: AlamBique editei a sua pergunta, era isso que vc queria saber?

Comment: Exato! Estou começando com o Identity. É a primeira vez que tento implanta-lo em uma solução. Então sei que essa pergunta deve soar até boba, mas qualquer dica já me ajuda.

Comment: Vamos esperar a opinião de alguém mais experiente, mas eu ficaria na segunda opção pelo pouco que conheço.

Comment: Essa pergunta não se encaixa no site porque só aceita respostas baseadas em opinião. Mas, tentando colaborar contigo, eu geralmente opto por deixar tudo que é relativo ao usuário na mesma tabela (`AspNetUsers`, por exemplo), não vejo sentido em manter duas tabelas pra mesma coisa.

Comment: Se for o caso, parece que estou ferrado. Kkkkkk! Não sou familiarizdo com CodeFirst, Vi algumas resposta aqui no Stack Overflow, mas só em inglês e confesso que não entendi bem. Por exemplo:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity

Aí te pergunto: Onde estaria esta [public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser] para que eu adicione as propriedades? Ou eu devo criar ela?

Comment: Será que conhece algum tutorial em português que possa me indicar?

Comment: @AlamBique Você poderia mudar o "tom" da sua pergunta para algo como: "Posso editar personalizar a tabela AspNetUsers do Identity?", dessa forma, sua pergunta não seria mais encaixada como baseada em opiniões e você ainda iria ter o seu "tutorial em português" =D

Comment: @LINQ Obrigado pela dica. Farei isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MVP Eduardo Pires tem dois artigos abordando justamente isso, aconselho você a dar uma olhada lá, são ótimos conteúdos.

[Tutorial identity completo](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/08/asp-net-identity-tutorial-completo/)

[Customizando a tabela de usuários](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/03/asp-net-identity-customizando-cadastro-usuarios/)